# How to connect Python to VirtualBox using RDP or RFB?

Tags: python, virtualbox, rdp

Is there a way to access the screen of a stock version of a headless `VirtualBox` 4.x remotely using `RDP` with Python or access it using the VNC protocol?

I want to be able to access the boot screen (F12), too, so I cannot boot a VNC server in the Guest as the Guest is not yet booted.

Note that I already have an `RFB` version in pure `Python`, however stock `VirtualBox` seems not to support `VNC` style remote connections, OTOH I somehow was unable to find a `Python` `RDP` library, sadly.

What I found so far but I do not want to use:

- A Java RDP client, however I do not want to switch horses, so I want to keep it Python
- `VirtualBox API` seems to provide Python with access to the framebuffer, but I am not completely sure.  However this then is bound to VirtualBox only, an RDP library (or letting VB talk RFB) would be more generic.

Notes:

- So what I need either is a way to add `VNC`/`RFB` support to an original `VirtualBox` (`.vbox-extpack`?)
- or find some `RDP` library written in pure `Python`.
- It must be available on at least all platforms for which VirtualBox is available.

If neither is possible, I think I will try the VirtualBox API in Python.

Comment: I currently go for VirtualBox OSE, but this is not yet fully complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [rdpy](https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy)? It's built on top of twisted.

Comment: `rdpy` looks promising, thanks, and was created 2013.  OTOH my question is from 2011, and newer versions of VirtualBox support RFB.  Also `KVM` and `virsh` are mature now, so I switched to them, as everything is "Linux built in" this way.  Anyway I accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Jython, which ought to be able to integrate  natively with the Java library you already have?

Comment: No.  Running a JVM is not an option.  I'd rather get rid of Python as well if there would be a way to do screenshots of VMs and send artificial keystrokes to VMs without any third party tool.